# Python- Beautiful Soup: Get the geo-coordinates (Lat and Lon) as a list from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, maps, bing-maps

I am trying to extract the geo-coordinates of a particular area http://www.zillow.com/richardson-tx/ which consists of real estate information (houses for sale). These are represented by points. I would like to get the coordinates of these points. I have been using the below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.zillow.com/richardson-tx/'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
print (soup.prettify())
print(soup.find_all('data-latitude'))
```

Can any one please help me out in providing me the right approach to extract the coordinate values. They are mentioned like s with itemprop=geo.

For example, when we search for properties in Richardson on zillow in Chrome. We open the dev tools (F12) and I tried typing this in the console so as to locate:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script'); 
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"; 
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Press Enter, then I tried like:

```
 jQuery('span[itemprop=geo]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery looks like it was correct, you just didn't translate it correctly into BeautifulSoup.

```
coord_tags = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"itemprop":"geo"})
# <span itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
#        <meta content="32.978499" itemprop="latitude"/>
#        <meta content="-96.728306" itemprop="longitude"/>
# </span>
```

The tag in the comments is an example of an item that was returned in the list `coord_tags`. This code will find all of the `<span>` tags with an attribute `itemprop` equal to `geo`.

For here, each span contains a longitude and latitude, so you can iterate over each item of the list to pull those out.  You want the `content` attribute of the `meta` tag with `itemprop` `longitude` and `latitude`.  The following code will get that information and place it into a tuple.

```
coordinates = [
       (
         c.find("meta", attrs={"itemprop":"latitude"}).attrs["content"],
         c.find("meta", attrs={"itemprop":"longitude"}).attrs["content"] 
       ) 
       for c in coord_tags
]
# ('-96.728306', '32.978499')
```

The tuple in the comments is an example of one of the items in the list created by this list comprehension.

Comment: The jquery I have written is entered in the Dev console of the chrome. Should I include the jquery in Python too??

Comment: Nope! Your Python is just fine.  I was trying to say that your JQuery selection was correct, you just needed to do the equivalent in BeautifulSoup.  If you attach this code to the end of yours, it should work.

Comment: Sure, I will be adding your code in my .py file and check for the result

Comment: I am getting only 26 points. But there are around 159 points in the map that I have mentioned.

Comment: What you are seeing on your page and what comes through when you make the call via `requests` does not always line up. It could also be that there are multiple elements holding coordinates.  If you find all of those elements though, you can use this answer to pull out the coordinates.

Comment: http://www.zillow.com/richardson-tx/ we can see here around 159 points represented. Is it possible to verify whether all these points have lat lon coordinates?